# Kohana ErrorException [ 8 ]

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

After installing and configuring Kohana, I renamed the install.php file (according to the user guide). But when I now go to localhost/kohana, I get the following error:

```
 ErrorException [ 8 ]: Array to string conversion ~ SYSPATH/classes/Kohana/Log/Writer.php [ 81 ]
```

I couldn't find a solution elsewhere on the web. Does anyone have any ideas how this can be fixed? Thanks!

Comment: Kohana has its own forum. This isn't a programming, bug a software product support problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Kohana 3.3 version bug. Check [here](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/11567/kohana-3-3-strtr-array-to-string-conversion-issue-in-kohana_log_writer/p1) for more detials.

Answer (score 4):

This is hotfix for that bug. Hope this help someones else
https://github.com/kohana/core/commit/82b470b2827470da37b0e6771b77c369c3d2e5fb

**classes/Kohana/Log/Writer.php**

```
 public function format_message(array $message, $format = "time --- level: body in   file:line")
    {
     $message['time'] = Date::formatted_time('@'.$message['time'], Log_Writer::$timestamp, Log_Writer::$timezone, TRUE);
     $message['level'] = $this->_log_levels[$message['level']];

-    // FIX: $message should consist of an array of strings
-    $message = array_filter($message, 'is_string');
-
-    $string = strtr($format, $message);
+    $string = strtr($format, array_filter($message, 'is_scalar'));

     if (isset($message['additional']['exception']))
     {
       $message['body'] = $message['additional']['exception']->getTraceAsString();
       $message['level'] = $this->_log_levels[Log_Writer::$strace_level];

 -     $string .= PHP_EOL.strtr($format, $message);
 +     $string .= PHP_EOL.strtr($format, array_filter($message, 'is_scalar'));
     }

   return $string;
```

Noticed that '+' means line added, '-' means line removed from v3.3

Comment: This is link only answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.